# can analytics services such as Flurry give me information regarding the type of devices users have

Tags: android, analytics

Should I save the phone model on my database in order to understand my clients, Or should I rely on Flurry for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flurry provide this kind of information, in the technical section:

[image]